# how to copy latest updated single file using ant?

Tags: java, ant

I am using ant to build my application with timestamp. It is running currently. Now i want to get the latest updated folder so that i can copy that to any other folder.

I tried and it is printing me the latest file only but its not copying that file to another folder.

Please help me

```
    <tstamp> 
        <format property="timestamp" pattern="dd-MMM-yy" locale="en,UK"/> 
    </tstamp>

        <timestampselector property="latest.modified">
          <path>
            <fileset dir="${Engine.stagging.dir}">                
            </fileset>
          </path>
        </timestampselector>

    <copy todir="${prjHop.release.dir}" flatten="true" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir="${Engine.stagging.dir}">
            <include name="${latest.modified}"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
```

Also tried this to copy

```
<copy todir="${prjHop.release.dir}">
   <path refid="${latest.modified}"/>
</copy>

 <echo message="${latest.modified}" />
```

this echo is printing current folder and file name. I just want to copy the file inside that folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `${latest.modified}` contains the absolute path of the file. When you use this path in the `include` nested element, the `copy` task will not find the file in the directory specified in `${Engine.stagging.dir}` and hence will not copy it.

You can do the copy as follows:

```
<copy file="${latest.modified}" todir="${prjHop.release.dir}"/>
```

Comment: You are the man ! Thanks a lot.. Its working :) :)

This is what i wanted to :)